# Determine availability of street view for a specific latitude and longitude in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, google-street-view

In my native android application I'm loading Street View for the given latitude and longitude.  But if the street view is not available for that specific location it just shows a grey screen.  The maps application can do it but I can't seem to find a way using the android api, maps api or any of the intent uri's.

Following is the code that I'm using to show Street view and it's working fine.

```
    String uriString = "google.streetview:cbll="+ latitude+","+longitude+"&cbp=1,0,,1,-5.27&mz=21";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    Intent streetViewIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   startActivity(streetViewIntent);
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on determining the availability of Street View with specific lat and long coordinates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236312/how-to-detect-if-google-streetview-is-available-in-an-address-coordinates

This should answer your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3865784/1278949 this might help